# Issues using sapply function in R

Tags: r, sapply, astronomy

I have multiple files (from different days) that all contain the same information that I want to be able to combine and analyse both together and separately. For example, I would like to be able to take averages of one of the columns for each day - and write the result to a new file - as well as the average for all files (or a weeks worth of files) and write that result to the same output file. I've been trying several methods but none quite work.
The code below I think is combining the files fine but the data (separated with a " ") are being joined together with a \t, so when I try to read the `$name` row it doesn't exist. How do I fix this so the headers and data remain separated and can be read individually?

````
data<- sapply(datafiles, function(x)read.table(file=paste0(x),
fill = TRUE,  header= TRUE,    sep=" ",        
                        stringsAsFactors = TRUE, quote = ""))

#separating STARLINK (SL) satellites from entire list
SL<- data[grepl("^SLINK", data$name), ]```
````